# Algorithm to partition a set into subsets of max weight

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms

I have a big set $S$ of elements $e_i$, each $e_i$ characterized by an integer weight $w_i$. I would like an algorithm to split set $S$ into subsets $S_j$ such that:

1. The sum of weights in each subset never exceeds 100
2. The number of subsets is minimized

I guess one has to somehow minimize the difference 100 - (sum of weights) in each subset.

Coming from a computer science background, I wonder whether Mathematicians have devised an algorithm for this problem.

Comment: It is called [bin packing problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem), and sure, some algorithms exists, but no polynomial algorithm has been found for the general case (it is an NP-complete problem and doesn't even admit a PTAS).

Comment: Thank you so much, mister!

Comment: @dtldarek if you write your comment as an answer, I'll vote for it (and maybe check it, if nothing better comes up)

Comment: As with many difficult combinatorial optimization problems, once a *feasible* solution is found, heuristics to search for improved solutions are of practical value.  Some terms you should look for in connection with the one-dimensional bin packing problem are: hill climbing, simulated annealing, and hybrid genetic algorithm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is called [bin packing problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem), and is an NP-complete problem which doesn't admit a [PTAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial-time_approximation_scheme). In other words, there is no polynomial-time algorithm that gives exact or even arbitrarily-good approximation algorithm.

There is an algorithm called first-fit-decreasing with bound $FFD \leq \frac{11}{9}OPT + 4$. To apply it, you should consider the items one by one in order of non-increasing weight, and then put each of them in the first bin that will not exceed the constraint.

The proof of the bound can be found in a paper *"Worst-case performance bounds for simple one-dimensional packing algorithms"* by D. S. Johnson, A. Demers, J. D. Ullman, M. R. Garey and R. L. Graham which appeared in SIAM Journal of Computing, Vol. 3, No. 4, December 1974 and can be found [here](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~fan/ron/papers/74_04_one_dimensional_packing.pdf).

You can also find an overview with a bit more details [here](http://www.or.deis.unibo.it/kp/Chapter8.pdf).

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$